# Check if phone number is in valid fromat

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to check for mobile numbers in the Rotterdam, Netherlands.

Basically I need to check if it starts with `+31`, than is it followed by `6` or `06` and than if it is followed by 7 digits.

If you have a better form to check for Rotterdam mobile numbers, please suggest it!

Unfortunately I am a beginner with regex and could not really put together my own for this simple task. Can you help me with an example?

Thanks!

Comment: So take a stab at creating a regular expression, and post back with what you came up with and how it does or does not meet your needs.

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) library.It is very powerful to validate various phone numbers